# Use Long as the start of a Range

Tags: excel, vba, import

I have a spreadsheet that needs to pull data once a day when a new file comes in.

It's responsibilities are:

- Start at the bottom populated row (of Column C)
- Fill the Date for today and make it static
- Delete data at the top of the sheet over 2 months old

I'm sure I can work out the other two tasks, but I'm struggling pulling the lastrow as the point in the range

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, lastRow As Long

Set ws = Worksheets("Report")
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1 ' bottom populated cell of Column "C", plus 1

   'Error on this "line" below
    With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
            "TEXT;N:\etc\etc\etc\FMSQRY.CSV", Destination:= _
            ws.Range(Cells(lastRow, 3)))
        'Data Import here
    End With
```

Classic error 1004 - range of object worksheet failed

But when I use the same method to use lastRow for the selection of `N2:N` in a different workbook (and different project) it works fine

```
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row                  'Finds the bottom populated row

With ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 14), ws.Cells(LastRow, 14))               'Selects N2:N
    'magical formula
End With
```

Comment: What line is giving you the error?

Comment: `With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
            "TEXT;N:\etc\etc\etc\FMSQRY.CSV", Destination:= _
            ws.Range(Cells(lastRow, 3)))` is where the error is. If I have the range as a Absolute range, it works fine

Comment: Have you tried, `ws.cells(lastRow,3)` ?

Comment: So stupid I didn't think to remove the range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code. Check that you don't need the range before cells:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, lastRow As Long

Set ws = Worksheets("Hoja1")
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1 ' bottom populated cell of Column "C", plus 1


    With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
            "TEXT;N:\etc\etc\etc\FMSQRY.CSV", Destination:= _
            ws.Cells(lastRow, 3))
        'Data Import here
    End With
```

Comment: Thanks - I just didn't think to remove the range